# How to show failure message for a loop with when in ansible?

Tags: ansible

```yaml
---
- name: install httpd and mod_ssl
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - vars/package_list.yaml
  tasks:
    - name: install httpd,firewalld and mod_ssl
      yum:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: latest
      loop: "{{ package_list }}"
      when: >
        ( ansible_facts['distribution'] == 'Ubuntu' )
        or
        ( ansible_facts['distribution'] == 'CentOS' and ansible_facts['distribution'] == 'Fedora' and ansible_facts['distribution_version'] is version( '8' , '>=') )

    # some other tasks.
```

How can I send a failure message if task `install httpd, firewalld and mod_ssl` fails based on the condition that if distribution is **ubuntu** then proceed with the install or if the distribution is '**CenOS**' ( Not '**Fedora**' ) with `version >= '8'` then proceed with the install or show a failure message.
If the condition is not met then it exits with the failure message or else it continues with the rest of the play.

something like:

```
if ( 
     ( distro == 'Ubuntu' ) or 
     ( distro == 'CentOS' and distro != 'Fedora' and version >= 8)
   )
    then install httpd, firewalld, mod_ssl and proceed further
else
    print "Error: requirements not met for setup"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify the pattern:

1. fail early if your target does not meet the requirement
2. go on with the rest of your tasks if it does

Note: I'm not sure I fully understand your condition which differs in your example playbook and pseudo code and is not really clear in both cases. So this is just a layout example. Put whatever condition is needed.

Moreover:

- although it is possible, using yum on Ubuntu looks a bit awkward.
- looping over yum is discouraged. You should pass the list of packages directly in the name attribute (fixed below)

```yaml
---
- name: install something on my supported targets
  hosts: all

  vars_files:
    - vars/package_list.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Fail if the target isn't supported
      ansible.builtin.fail:
        msg: target isn't supported
      when: my_target_condition_is_false
         
    - name: install packages on supported target
      ansible.builtin.yum:
        name: "{{ package_list }}"
        state: latest

    # some other tasks.
```